# Using a global variable as an argument in a ruby method

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm doing a Ruby course on Udemy, I'm trying to understand why this code works. It takes any two numbers and multiplies them.

```
def multiply(first_num, second_num)
  first_num.to_f * second_num.to_f
end

puts "Enter the first number"
first_number = gets.chomp
puts "Enter the second number"
second_number = gets.chomp

puts "The first number multiplied by the second number is #{multiply(first_number, second_number)}"
```

The method sets two arguments, and then uses them. Then two numbers are stored, one in first_number and one in second_number. In the final print, instead of using `first_num` and `second_num`, first_number and second_number are used instead of first_num and second_num. I would expect the code to fail because it's not using the initial arguments within the method. Why does it work?

Edit: My original question mentioned global variables, I've edited it to remove those references, along with the other things mentioned that made the question confusing. Also the question has been answered. What I really was trying to ask was, "Why were two variables not contained within a method, used as arguments in the method?" I didn't realize that was how it worked. Thanks to @sawa for setting me straight, and teaching me some stuff about Ruby I hadn't learned yet.

Comment: Where is "the final print"? I don't see any use of `print`. What is `first_num`? What is `second_num`? I don't see them either. No global variables are set.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm really new to this. I thought that first_number = gets.chomp sets a global variable, it basically asks for a number via input. it also looks like somehow my initial comments were cut off on the question. I'll try to clarify it better.

Comment: It's Ruby, so 'puts' prints it to console. I tried to edit the question, please let me know if it's still not clear and I'll try to clarify. I'm new to programming and stack overflow,

Comment: Nope, Ruby has a method called `print`, and it is different from `puts`. You should not use that term so ambiguously or vaguely. And you haven't answered what `first_num` and `second_num` are.

Comment: first_num and second_num are just any two numbers.

Comment: I see. You are mentioning the variables used inside the method.

Comment: Stack overflow is prompting me to move the discussion to a chat. can we do that?

Comment: No need of that.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you clarify, please: what global variables are you talking about? I don't see any global variables in the code you posted. Please, post the *actual* code you are asking about, containing the global variables. Secondly, what are "internal variables"? There is no such thing in Ruby. Ruby has only 5 kinds of variables: local variables, instance variables, class hierarchy variables (try to avoid them), global variables (do not use them, ever), and "constant variables". Thirdly, there is no call to `print` in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. Really new at coding, and I was trying to describe things in a way that would (hopefully) make sense. I deleted mention of global variables etc within the question already. I'm so new to Ruby that I didn't even know global variables were declared using $, among other miss-steps in my attempt at explaining my question. I will try to re-edit the question, although it's been answered by @sawa already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how a program is read and is executed. In particular, you seem to have a wrong idea about the timing in which a method is called.

When your script is executed, in the top part of the script, the method `multiply` is **defined**, not executed, at that point (Method execution is only done when it is called with particular arguments).

Then **local** variables, not global ones, `first_number` and `second_number` are set according to the input from the console.

Then, within the argument of `puts`, the method `multiply` is **called** with the arguments `first_number` and `second_number`.

Within the method **execution**, not definition, of `multiply`, the given `first_number` and `second_number` are assigned to `first_num` and `second_num` respectively, which can be accessed only within the method execution.

The calculated value is returned from the method `multiply`, and is put in the `#{}` part of the argument of `puts`. There, the method `to_s` is applied to the value, and becomes part of what is output.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand it now. I really appreciate you taking the time to walk me through my first stack overflow question.

Comment: Good to know it helped.

Comment: I have limited experience in programming. I didn't realize that Ruby uses $ to declare a global variable. I thought if it was defined outside of a method, that made it 'global'. I have a lot to learn.